# SQL Server 2012 error: each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

My code is like this

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getprocbyproc]
    @flg varchar(2),
    @qaaprvdt char(8), 
    @dbo varchar(20),
    @plantid char(1)
AS
    DECLARE @dynamicSQL varchar(8000) 
    DECLARE @datemth char(6) 
    DECLARE @dateday char(2) 
    DECLARE @FXTIME char(4) 
    DECLARE @TBL varchar(20) 
    DECLARE @def varchar(20) 
    DECLARE @OUTDAT CHAR(20) 

    SET @datemth = substring(@qaaprvdt,1,6)
    SET @dateday = substring(@qaaprvdt,7,2)

    IF @flg = 'QA' AND @dbo = 'PRCDAILYQA'
    BEGIN
        SET @TBL  = 'DAILYQA'
        SET @OUTDAT = 'CO.QAAPRVDT'
    END

    IF @plantid = '1' 
    BEGIN
        SET @def = "SQDPRCDEF1"
    END

    IF @flg = 'QA' AND @plantid = '1'
    BEGIN
        SET @dynamicSQL =  'insert into PrcdailyQA' +
                           '(process, seqno, qaamon, qaaday, orderno,  
                             ingotno, theopcs, cwacc, pwacc, pwout, 
                             procyld, prodyld, plantid, prodline) ' +
                           '(SELECT distinct(b.PROCNO),  b.proseq, "' + 
                           @datemth + '" , "' + @dateday +     
                           '", a.orderno, a.ingotno, a.theopcs, a.cwacc, a.pwacc, a.pwout, a.COprocyld, a.COprodyld, a.plantid, a.prodline ' +
                           'FROM DailyQA a , SQDPRCDEF1 b ' +
                           'WHERE a.qaamon = ' + @datemth  + '  and a.qaaday= ' + @DATEDAY  + ' and     a.plantid="1"' +  
                           'GROUP BY b.procno, b.proseq, a.orderno, a.ingotno, a.theopcs, a.cwacc, a.pwacc, a.pwout, a.COprocyld, a.COprodyld, a.plantid, a.prodline) '
```

Now when I to execute it returns no error. But when I try to execute it at runtime, it returns error

> Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

I already refer this http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/group-by-expression-contain-one-column-not-an-outer-reference/ and try to change the group by statement, also return error.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `DISTINCT` in a `GROUP BY` query.  Also, you are selecting columns which do not either appear in the `GROUP BY` clause or are aggregates of columns.  Removing `DISTINCT` along with the non-aggregate columns would leave you with the following query:

```
INSERT INTO PrcdailyQA (process, seqno, qaamon, qaaday, orderno, ingotno, theopcs, cwacc,
                        pwacc, pwout, procyld, prodyld, plantid, prodline)
SELECT b.PROCNO, b.proseq, a.orderno, a.ingotno, a.theopcs, a.cwacc, a.pwacc, a.pwout,
       a.COprocyld, a.COprodyld, a.plantid, a.prodline
FROM DailyQA a, SQDPRCDEF1 b
WHERE a.qaamon = ' + @datemth  + '  AND a.qaaday = ' + @DATEDAY  + ' AND a.plantid = "1"'
GROUP BY b.procno, b.proseq, a.orderno, a.ingotno, a.theopcs, a.cwacc, a.pwacc, a.pwout,
         a.COprocyld, a.COprodyld, a.plantid, a.prodline
```

Comment: Is `a.qaamon` and `a.qaaday ` missing in the SELECT statement? btw, I would suggest not to do dynamic sql too

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have applied your query but still when in run time, it return the same error. Do you think my select statement is the problem?

Comment: I need to do in dynamic as i use to call this on stored procedure. @Eric

Comment: My advice to you: Get your target query working without any dynamic SQL in the workbench.  Just hard code realistic values for the variables.  Once you have that working completely, without any error, then return to your dynamic SQL problem.

Comment: Yes, I have change the code without using dynamic, no error. The query can run without problem. I wonder why in the sql 2005 this return no error but in the sql 2012, return error.

Comment: Now you are dealing with two variables, first the SQL Server version, and second static vs. dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not aggregating on any fields (i.e. using `sum`, `max`, etc.), you don't really need to use a `group by` clause in your example.

However, what are you trying to do in the `from` clause?  You are currently creating a `cartesian product` of the 2 tables -- you aren't joining the tables on any common field.

Without knowing more, I'd be more inclined to remove the `group by` clause altogether, and have something like this:

```
insert into ...
select distinct b.PROCNO, b.proseq, ...
from ...
where ...
```

Btw, in general I wouldn't recommend using commas in a `from` clause, use `join` instead.

Comment: Actually I have used this code in sql 2005, no error. Now when migrate to 2012, this error appear.